# How can I refactor these simple functions and make them more DRY?

Tags: ruby, oop, refactoring, dry

I'm just practicing object-oriented design. This is a simple budget calculator. What can I do to make this code cleaner and more DRY? If I recall correctly, it's a Ruby convention to have terse classes and functions. While my functions are short, the class itself is large.

I see that I am dividing by 12 in a few places. Can that be DRYed?

```
class Dylan
  def salary
    80000
  end

  def tax_rate
    0.28
  end

  def net_salary
    (1 - tax_rate) * salary
  end

  def monthly_budget
    net_salary / 12.0
  end

  def car_payment
    457.0
  end

  def car_insurance
    2600 / 12.0
  end

  def gas
    2400 / 12.0     
  end  

  def rent
    2000
  end

  def food
    300
  end

  def left_with
    monthly_budget - car_insurance - car_payment - gas - rent - food
  end
end

d = Dylan.new

p d.left_with
```

Comment: are all the values static? if some are static tell which one?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by static? @SachinSingh

Comment: i mean constant, rent will always be 2000 etc.?

Comment: Hmm... In that regard I think they're all constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:

```
class Dylan
  SALARY = 80000
  TAX_RATE = 0.28
  CAR_PAYMENT = 457.0        
  CAR_INSURANCE = 2600 / 12.0
  GAS = 2400 / 12.0 
  RENT = 2000
  FOOD = 300

  def net_salary
    (1 - TAX_RATE) * SALARY
  end

  def monthly_budget
    net_salary / 12.0
  end

  def expenditure
    CAR_INSURANCE + CAR_PAYMENT + GAS + RENT + FOOD
  end

  def remaining_income
    monthly_budget - expenditure 
  end
end

d = Dylan.new

p d.remaining_income
```

As salary is constant in class you can get it by scope resolution operator.

```
Dylan::SALARY =>  80000
```

hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks for that! I like that you consolidated all of the costs in an expenditure function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to obtain the SALARY value from the object? Something like `d.SALARY # => 80000`